# Convert Float Value To id. How can i do this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I store a float value in an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585384/how-can-i-store-a-float-value-in-an-nsarray)

it wants id value but my variable is float. and i want to import tmpValue array 1. object. How Can i do this?

```
tmpToplam =  tmpToplam + ([[self.closeData objectAtIndex:i]floatValue] - tmpToplam)* expCarpan;


            [tmpValue replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:tmpToplam];
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to wrap your floats in NSNumber, as id is just a pointer to "any Objective-C object" and NSNumber is the appropriate Object-C class to wrap numbers:

```
float a = 2.0;
float b = 3.0;
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:a];
NSNumber *bNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:b];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aNumber, bNumber, nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

`id` is a pointer to an objective c object, in the case of cocoa generally an `NSObject`, so you need to wrap your float in an `NSNumber` (which inherits from `NSObject`). `NSNumber` can handle many other primitive types.

Comment: +1. To be more specific, NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue (which of course ultimately derives from NSObject).

Comment: True. NSValue is more general and can be used for structs, pointers and other things.

Comment: Changed my answer to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert tmpToplam into string using NSString StringWithFormat ? Actually in an array, you need to put an object and float is not considered object. String is, of course, an object.

Comment: Convert a float to a string? That's not a good idea at all.

Comment: NSNumber is the way to do it, not NSString.

Comment: My bad. NSNumber is definitely the better way, but NSString is also possible(of course not a good way).